At the end a couple rips through the advertisements surrounding them
Identify a movie where at the end, a couple rips through the advertisements surrounding them in a dystopian city, and escapes into a beautiful countryside outside the walls that has been forgotten by others.  I thought it was Brazil, but that's not it.
Edit: more detail: I seem to remember that in the final scene they are driving on a highway where billboards line the sides edge to edge.  They stop the vehicle and look through them and see the natural world.  I probably saw this movie in the late 80s or 90s.

I agree with @Nobby - it really really sounds like Brazil.

I know you said it wasn't Brazil, but are you absolutely sure?
This clip fits your description to a tee... and if you tack on the horrible 'alternate' ending (for sensitive viewers) then you get even more pastoral scenes.
